# Need an alternative modern phrase

Tags: phrases

What would be a common/modern phrase for:
“If Mohammad can't go to the mountain, let the mountain come to Mohammad”?

Comment: I think this is still fairly common today.

Comment: It sounds a little religious tho. Not everyone will understand all cultures

Comment: How about A man’s gotta do what a man’s gotta do?

Comment: A modern phrase for *which meaning* of that sentence?

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with “If Mohammad can't go to the mountain, let the mountain come to Mohammad”. Are you _intending_ a play on the familiar saying?

Comment: Erm...the phrase is:  'If the mountain will not come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain', and it comes from Francis Bacon.

Answer (score 1):

The actual phrase is:

> 'If the mountain will not come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain',

...and it comes from Francis Bacon (Essays, 1665).

> Mahomet cald the Hill to come to him. And when the Hill stood still, he was neuer a whit abashed, but said; If the Hill will not come to Mahomet, Mahomet wil go to the hil.

[-Phrasefinder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-the-mountain-will-not-come-to-muhammad.html)

It is still used, although some might consider it archaic.

Comment: If the answer is undeserved because the question is un-researched, then maybe users should participate more in the VTC queue....